# Symfony: Showing the dev toolbar in "prod" environment

Tags: debugging, symfony1

I managed to interactively set the debugging mode of my symfony application On and Off for a user session with something like this:

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration($app,
                                                           $env, $debugging);
```

I know that the Web Debug Toolbar showing up or not does not depend on the value of $debugging, but the configuration of the current environment.

To this moment the only way that the toolbar appears is when $env = 'dev'.

I'd like to activate it when accessing the "prod" environment also.

I have this app setting:

```
prod:
  .settings:
    no_script_name:         true
    logging_enabled:        false
    web_debug:              true
    error_reporting:        <?php echo (E_ALL | E_STRICT)."\n" ?>

dev:
  .settings:
    error_reporting:        <?php echo (E_ALL | E_STRICT)."\n" ?>
    web_debug:              true
    cache:                  false
    no_script_name:         false
    etag:                   false
```

The toolbar is not being shown, apparently ignoring the "web_debug" setting.

If I echo(sfConfig::get('sf_web_debug')) I get "true".

¿How could I get the toolbar working?

Answer (score 2):

you also need to change the factory.yml . By default, there's no Logger in the 'prod'-environment.

Just comment out like this:

```
prod:
#  logger:
#    class:   sfNoLogger
#    param:
#      level:   err
#      loggers: ~
```

Answer (score 1):

From memory you have to change a value in your frontend php file. Compare the frontend.php and frontend_dev.php files in your web directory. Look for a difference where one is true and the other is false (I think it's the last parameter).

The lines are:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false));
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

change to:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', true));
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

Comment: That's what I am doing but, while the third parameter means "debugging", it's function has little to do with the debug toolbar being shown or not.  The second parameter is a label that points to a whole set of configuration options.  When it's set to "prod" the environment it points to don't include the `web_debug: true` definition by default, while the "dev" environment does.  The documentation says that defining `web_debug: true` on the "prod" environment would suffice, but it's not working in my application.

Comment: Hmm, I was sure that you needed a combination of enabling the debug and debug bar in the config and also enabling debug in the frontend.php file. Guess not though...

Comment: According to the documentation that's the answer, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There's the possibility that it is working, but the styles are being overriden or the bar is being hidden somewhere. Check your page source to see whether it's being added in (I assume you've checked and it's not though).