# How enable debugging toolbar in prod environment of a Symfony2 project?

Tags: symfony, toolbar

I have an existing project and just would like to know which files and what should I change to make visible the debug toolbar in the prod environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony: Showing the dev toolbar in "prod" environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198375/symfony-showing-the-dev-toolbar-in-prod-environment)

Comment: I am not in the same situation the other question implied, I just need the lines and files I need to change to show it.

Comment: @AlexanderGuz the answer is referring a different version of the framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change in the `AppKernel.php` file in order to enable the bundle in the prod environment also and change the route moving from the `routing_dev.yml` to the `routing.yml` the bundle definition route. Then add the configuration in the `config.yml` also.

As Example:

<kbd>AppKernel.php</kbd>

```
        // Move this outside the if statement
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'), true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }
```

<kbd>routing.yml</kbd>

```
#add this

_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler
```

<kbd>config.yml</kbd>

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
```

Hope this help

Comment: The site goes blank.
Maybe the project has some changed files that make this not possible :x

Comment: hi @MatheusOliveira check my update. In case of error (blank page) check in the log files (app/logs/prod.log) for the exception. Let me know